# [iOS]Handle of receive push notification after User kill application manually

Tags: ios, background, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

If user killed application manually, after that application receive push notification, how can i increase the badge number on application icon

1. I try to turn on "backgroud mode", selected "remote notification" in Xcode Capabilities
2. add follow source code in AppDelegate

```java
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
}
```

3. install application, after it launched, kill it manually.
4. I use push notification tool to send push notification with

> "contentAvailable : 1"

5. Application received notification (Notice pop up), but application Icon Badge Number was not display, I don't know how to do that

Could you help me please, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal APNS payload is as following:

```
{
   "aps":{
       "alert": "Hello, world!",
       "sound": "default"
       "badge": "2"
   }
}
```

And silent APNS push payload is as following:

```
aps {
    content-available: 1
    alert: {...}
}
```

When a silent push notification reaches device, user does not know anything about the notification. But your app gets the notification and app will be given some time to download new content and present it to the user.

If you kill App, user can't get any alert when a silent push notification reaches device! So check your payload for this!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found my payload is like this, {
    "aps": {
        "alert": "test",
        "content-available": 1
    },......
}, is it wrong? I want to show Badge Number on icon when app was killed, Could you please help me?

Comment: You are using `silent APNS` and if you want to show `Badge Number` when app was killed, change `silent APNS` to `normal APNS`, that needs you modify payload as described within my answer above

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try~~

Comment: There are two blogs that describe `normal APNS` and `silent APNS` which maybe help you! [normal APNS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).............[silent APNS](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)

Comment: Sorry, I use silent APNS, and killed app, I still can receive notification, and notification also can display, but didReceiveRemoteNotification was not called. If I use normal APNS, Badge Number only be setted (over write) when receive notification every time

Comment: “ If I use normal APNS, Badge Number only be setted (over write) when receive notification every time” ....So, what's your question

Comment: Sorry ,my requirement is like this : For example, I use silent APNS, and killed app, after receive notification, Badge Number is 1, receive second notification, Badge Number is 2... but If I use normal APNS, Badge Number only be setted (over write) when receive notification every time, Could you please teach me how can i do that?

Comment: Badge count is always sent by server side. Caculate and update it with other value then check.It definitely reflect on IOS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @SeraZheng is it possible to get Silent Push event in application-delegate method when app is terminated. I checked with badge thing & it seems it's working fine but how to notify application about this event. Any suggestion !!